# How to add button with name in magento admin with module

Tags: magento

I have tried with below code but it only show the button without name, but i need name text with button.

```
<logger_API_button translate="label">
     <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
     <label>Send</label>
     <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
     <sort_order>77</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</logger_API_button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `<frontend_type>` tag twice.

just write

```
<logger_API_button translate="label">
     <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
     <label>Send</label>
     <sort_order>77</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</logger_API_button>
```

Comment: I removed <frontend_type>text</frontend_type> tag but still it's not working.  I want button name should be on button, but <label>Send</label> tag shows "Send" label at left side of button